# Searching for a list of values in Pandas series and masking the matches

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search for a list of values within a Pandas series and write the matches to a new column.

input:

```
vals = ['john', 'jane']

col1         
john doe
jane doe
billy j.
```

desired output:

```
col1          col2
john doe      john
jane doe      jane
billy j.      nan
```

I tried to stay away from for loops and do it with Pandas methods but could not get the result.

With the bare python code below, I can print the matches but can't write them to the corresponding rows in col2. Also, it is obviously not efficient for larger datasets.

```
for i in vals:
    for j in df.col1:
        if i in j:
            print("match\t",  i,'in:\t',j)
        else:
            print('-')

output:
match    john in:    john doe
-
-
-
match    jane in:    jane doe
-
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is the desired output if there are multiple matches per row? e.g. col1 containing value `jane john doe`

Comment: Ideally all matches with a separator in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that could also handle multiple vals per row, concatenating them with comma:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: ','.join([v for v in vals if v in x])).replace('', np.nan)
```

Output:

```
       col1  col2
0  john doe  john
1  jane doe  jane
2  billy j.   NaN
```

---

Another option using [`pandas.Series.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(vals)
df['col2'] = df.col1.str.findall(pat).apply(','.join)
```